# Select iframe parent of an element in iframe, doing outside the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this html page:

```
<div> this is the outside page </div>
<iframe id="ifr">
    (#document node)
        <html>
            <p> a node within iframe </p>
        </html>
</iframe>
```

Loading js in the **outside** page. How can I select the `<iframe>` object, by using the `<p>` element inside the iframe?

Most web resources work on "selecting parent elements from **inside** iframe" (using `window.parent`). Their js is loaded within the iframe. Again, I'm running the script in the outside.

I have managed to get the `#document` node -

```
$(clicked_object).parents('html').parent()
```

where `clicked_object` means I clicked on the `<p>` tag inside the iframe. 
This gives the `#document` node of the iframe page, without any problem. 
But if I write

```
$(clicked_object).parents('html').parent().parent()
```

it gives `[]`.

Other literatures teach how to select the `<iframe>` element by id (such as `$('iframe#ifr')`), from the parent page. But by this way I can't get the *parent* of an in-iframe element.

---

So, one possible way is that add a `onclick` attribute to the `<p>` element, calling a parent listener function, and passing something (like `#document` node) as argument; then look over all `<iframe>` elements matching the specific `#document`.

Comment: Try window. - to the iframe content, window is the iframe and parent is the window of the main page

Comment: @mplungjan I'm running js in the outside page so `window` gives the window of the main page.

Comment: Hey Yvon, I am trying to do the same thing. If you were able to resolve this, can you provide an answer

Comment: @Ashfaqnisar Let me get back to you later. This post was many years ago, and I don't remember what was going on at the time. It seemed that I didn't find any solution. But things could have changed over the past years.

Comment: Ohhh got it @Yvon, that would be great

Answer (score 1):

if you use javascript you could use this (assuming you used onclick or addeventlistener:

```
function something(clicked)
{
    var ifrparent = clicked.parentNode.parentNode;
}
```

EDIT:
if the p tag is in the src of the iframe, then in your onclick function, you would use

```
var ifrparent = window.frameElement.parentNode;
```

and that should return the iframes parent

Comment: OH wait is the p in the document that is the source of the iframe?

Comment: not very sure what you mean, but the `p` is loaded from another html source, and that page is loaded as an iframe in the main page.

Comment: `window.frameElement` gives `null` again.... Because I'm running the js in the main page, so `window` will always pick the main page.

Comment: oh the js is in the main page. well do you have any particular reason for wanting to come from inside the source? why not just get the iframe by its id?

Comment: here we can discuss in chat @Yvon